# XML returning null

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create a ticket system with XML in C#, but for some reason the values keep returning null. The Id Attribute is not null when getting it.

This is my loading method:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("ticketdata.xml");



        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement) {
            int id = int.Parse(node.Attributes[0].Value);
            string user = node["user"].Value;
            string platform = node["platform"].Value;
            string ttext = node["ttext"].Value;

            tickets.Add(new Ticket(id, user, platform, ttext));

        }
```

This is my XML file:

[XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkRPf.png) ( for some reason XML didn't work great in text)

I hope you guys could help me with this.

Comment: Follow the instructions.  Debug your code, examine your variables and see why they would return null.  Once you do this, if you haven't already found the issue, [edit] and update with what you did and what you found.  Then, @ me in the comments here.

Comment: @Stannies: use InnerText instead of Value property.

Comment: @JiříPolášek Thanks that worked!